# Battery light on

Tags: battery, mazda, tribute

The battery indicator on the dashboard of my Mazda Tribute (2005) suddenly came on while I was driving, and it has remained on throughout four hours of steady driving. What does this mean? I'm a bit skittish about it; I don't want something that'll hold me to ransom in a bad place. Please help

Answer (score 4):

This means that the charging system is not functioning.

Most likely it is not something as simple as a drive belt as you say you have been driving for four hours but have not complained about overheating.

This is likely to be the alternator - you need to get it checked as if you drive at night the headlights will cause a flat battery very quickly.